# How to resolve; Functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget-package, xamarin.uwp

I added the firebase pushnotifications plugin to my application. This works fine in Android, however when testing for UWP the application keeps crashing on this line in my App.Xaml.cs

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;
```

This is the error message:

*System.NotImplementedException: 'This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.'*

I have cleaned & rebuild the solution.
Deleted my project entirely and recloned it from github.
The Nuget package is installed on the mobile, android & UWP project, all 3 having the same version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your target package?  When you publish with Core as target the runtime version of Core is installed.  This should be compatible with all devices.  So I suspect you target is Net which is giving you the issue.

Comment: Target .Net Standard 2.0 which should be compatible according to the nuget package. Or am I not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: Net Standard 2.0 is compatible with Core 6 or 7.  Core 7 is really the latest Net Standard 2.1.  There are a lot of changes made when going from Net to Core so make sure you are using the latest nuget-package(s).  Check the dates of all the nuget packages.  If the dates are current than they should support UWP.  It is the older packages that are troublesome.

Comment: I think I've found the problem.. Nothing is being mentioned about UWP in the NuGet package. I think the package simply doens't support UWP.